# Local notification plugin installation for IONIC 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in ionic 3 project . I want to install the Local notification plugin for implementing the

notification feature in my project. But I can't install the local notfication plugin properly.

I don't know the correct verion of local notifcation plugin to My working environment.

Please tell me the correct version of local notifcation plugin.

I am using the following command to install the plugins

```
 $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification

 $ npm install @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

## My working Environment

cli Packages:

```
   @ionic/cli-utils:1.19.2

    ionic (Ionic CLI):3.20.0
```

global Packages:

```
   cordova    : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
   @ionic/app-scripts: 3.2.2

   cordova plaforms :ios 4.3.0

   ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.5
```

System:

```
  Node:v6.12.2

   npm:3.10.10

   OS:macOS

   Xcode:xcode 11.2 Build system
```

Please give me the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the documentation of ionicframework for Version 3, According to V3 you have to use the following commands to install **local notification** plugin.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications@4
```